# How to open a file with .key extension in UIWebView in an iPad app?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiwebview, ios5

In my app I have to show some PDF files, Videos and some .key files. To play all these files I am using UIWebView. PDFs and Videos are working fine. But this .key file is not working. .key file is a keynote file and it has some readable text and 2 videos. How can I play this in WebView. Below is the code for playing files in UIWebView.

```
AssetViewController *_assetViewController = [[AssetViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AssetViewController" bundle:nil];

_assetViewController.arrayforVideos=temparray;
[temparray release];
temparray=nil;

_assetViewController.assetName = @"Tome_Presentation";
_assetViewController.AssetType = @"key";
_assetViewController.assetNumber = 2;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_assetViewController animated:YES];
[_assetViewController release];
_assetViewController = nil;
```

I am using this same code to play PDFs, MP4s and KEY. I just change the assetName and AssetType and it works. Earlier this .key file was working, only videos were not playing which are included in this file. But now when client asked me to replace this file with a new one, its not working even though their extension is same. I can't find a way to fix it. Please help.

Regards,
PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that .key files are actually directories (e.g. they are bundles). Since UIWebView can only display the contents of files, not directories, you have to load a .key.zip, rather than a .key. This means that you have to zip the keynote file before presenting it in a UIWebView. For more information on this, check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html.

Comment: HI Alex, I followed your link and did it in same steps as given in that link. But still keynote file videos do not play. I found a keynote app on app store. I haven't tried it yet because its paid ($10). Do you think installing this Keynote app would help videos in my keynote file play in my app?

Comment: I doubt that buying the app would fix or change the behavior in your app. It may just be that WebKit limits keynote's capabilities.

Comment: So I should not risk $10 on buying that app as both the apps would be independent. Is there any other way I can play those videos in keynote file in my app?

Comment: I don't think so, unless you manually parse the keynote file.